Azure Pipeline is not running simple angular build in my environment
Trying to run pipeline in my environment .
enter image description here
The below is the error i get when i run simple angular application in my environment.

I am afraid we didn't see any error in the screenshot that you shared. It was the same logging information for agent job preparation as that of every succeeded agent job. Please share the error in text and your YAML pipeline definition with detailed reproducing steps provided. Thx.

yes but the yaml pipeline I have taken is simple one with npm installed and ng build. After agent job preparation the actual build was not happening

trigger:

main

pool:
name: nxt2kor
steps:


task: NodeTool@0
inputs:
versionSpec: '10.x'
displayName: 'Install Node.js'


script: |
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install
ng build --prod
displayName: 'npm install and build'
The above is my yaml file



I have taken simple angular code from developers to run

I could only know you build a simple code and just got to know a few steps of your YAML pipeline. So do you mean you agent job was not running at all? It didn't run checkout or any node installation or npm command?

What do the agents in your pool nxt2kor look like? Can you share a screenshot? Please don't add any personal or sensitive information like password, credentials, tokens, IP, etc.

may be agent was offline so i think i was getting the above error

What is the OS of your agent? Have you got a chance to check if the agent machine was offline in your Project Settings? If this was the issue, you may then access to the remote machine to run the agent and take it back online or configure it to run as service, so that the agent will be online automatically whenever the machine is started.

Hi @Anjumaara, May I ask if the answer below to enable your agent in the pool could help resolve the issue? Hope the suggestion helps? Thx.

Based on the further discussion, I can only reproduce the issue when there was no available agent in my self-hosted agent pool; the agent service might be taken offline or simply disabled.

If it was your case as well, please check in your Project Settings and enable your agent.
To take your agent back online, you may take the instructions in the documents below for reference.
For Linux self-hosted agent after configuration:
Run interactively
Run as a systemd service
For Windows self-hosted agent after configuration:
Run the agent
